# <input type="file"> change event firing again when navigating back to the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic file uploader. I upload a file, which triggers the change event (console.log). I navigate to a different page, then press the back button. The change event triggers again (the event is logged again to the console).

I am using Chrome. It doesn't happen with text inputs; only file. Anyone know why?

```
<input type="file" />

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    input.addEventListener("change", console.log, { once: true });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the input rendering is considered a `change` event. You could just check if there is a file available or not when it's fired and do nothing if there isn't one.

Comment: That's a really good idea. My next question: this still happens even if  I set `{ once: true }` (I edited my code above to reflect that). So the input would get rendered before the listener is attached, right?

Comment: So it logs twice with `once: true`?

Comment: Correct. I clear the console, navigate away, then press the back button and it logs again. Even with `once: true`.

Comment: That's odd, it only logs once for me.

Comment: Testing it with Chromium, it seems to cache the file. So, when you go back, the file is reloaded into the input which triggers the `change` event. Not sure if there's a way around that.

Comment: Which browser were you using where it only logged once? Or was it Chrome with the cache turned off?

Comment: Also, it seems like you've answered the question. I was mostly curious _why_ it was happening. If you plug that comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It was Brave (which uses Chromium) with the cache enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chromium (Brave) the file seems to be cached. So, when you go back, the file is loaded back into the input, triggering the `change` event.

One workaround would be to set the inputs value to an empty string on page-load:

```
<input type="file" />

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');

    window.addEventListener('load', () => (input.value = ''));
    input.addEventListener('change', console.log);
</script>
```

Comment: Update: I couldn't get the load event listener tactic to work, but I _was_ able to get it to work with setTimeout around the input event listener. So your initial analysis is still correct.